# How to make a text column in power bi dataset a numeric value

Tags: powerbi

I am working on a report and updated the power bi dataset with the most recent data. However, for some reason a column is recognizing the data as a string instead of numeric. I checked the excel file it is updated from, but in the excel file the column is considered numeric. Any idea how to fix this, as i cant use the data as a string. In addition, it would be beneficial if there was a way to change the dataset to just using the excel file, instead of having to use power bi datasets, is there any way to do that as well, as when i try to change datasets in only lets me view power bi datasets.
Thank you!

Comment: Check data column in your excel file. Probably for some unexpected value its failing to detect original datatype.

Answer (score 0):

In Power Query change the datatype to numeric.

Comment: Power query is inaccessible since it is a power bi dataset.